# Laravel Datatable ManyToMany relationship with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, datatable

**Offer.php** #model

```
use App\OfferCategory;
use App\OfferCountries;
use App\OfferCreative;
use App\OfferTools;
use App\OfferTraffic;

class Offer extends Model {
public function offer_countries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(OfferCountries::class);
}

public function offer_categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(OfferCategory::class);
}

public function offer_creatives() {
    return $this->hasMany(OfferCreative::class);
}

public function offer_tools() {
    return $this->hasMany(OfferTools::class);
}

public function offer_traffic() {
    return $this->hasMany(OfferTraffic::class);
}

public function platforms() {
    return $this->hasMany(Platform::class);
}
```

}

**OfferController.php**

```
 public function getMediaData() {
//        $model = Offer::with('offer_traffic');
//        return DataTables::eloquent($model)
//                        ->addColumn('traffic', function (Offer $user) {
//                            return $user->offer_traffic->map(function($post) {
//                                        return str_limit($post->allowed_traffic, 30, '...');
//                                    })->implode('<br>');
//                        })
//                        ->toJson();

        return datatables(DB::table('offers'))->toJson();
    }
```

I want to use all relation table given in offer.php and image in data table. I have tried with commented code in the controller but not able to get please help me to know where I'm doing wrong.

**OfferCountries.php**  #model

use App\Offer;

```
class OfferCountries extends Model {

   function offers() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class);
    }
}
```

[image: Database schema]

Comment: Check this documentation...  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how i would do,

In Offer.php

```
 class Offer extends Model {
    public function offer_countries() {
        return $this->hasMany(OfferOfferCountries::class,'offer_id','id');
    }

    public function offer_categories() {
        return $this->hasMany(OfferOfferCategories::class,'offer_id','id');
    }

    public function offer_creatives() {
        return $this->hasMany(OfferCreative::class,'offer_id','id');
    }

    public function offer_tools() {
        return $this->hasMany(OfferTools::class,'offer_id','id');
    }

    public function offer_traffic() {
        return $this->hasMany(OfferTraffic::class,'offer_id','id');
    }

    public function platforms() {
        return $this->hasMany(Platform::class,'offer_id','id');
    }
  }
```

In OfferOfferCountries.php

```
class OfferOfferCountries extends Model {
   public function countryDetail(){
     return $this->belongsTo(OfferCountries::class,'offercountry_id','id');
   }
}
```

In OfferOfferCategory.php

```
class OfferOfferCategory extends Model {
   public function categoryDetail(){
     return $this->belongsTo(OfferCategory::class,'offercategory_id','id');
   }
}
```

Now in the controller

```
public function getMediaData() {
        $data = Offer::with('offer_countries.countryDetail','offer_categories.categoryDetail','offer_creatives','offer_tools','offer_traffic','platforms')->get();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

}
```

This should give you an array of objects of everything. You can use pivot table but I like this way.

Comment: Thanks can you help with datatable i'm getting error  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)

Comment: It seems like there is an error somewhere in the code, likely to go to an infinite loop . Can't tell what is causing the issue without seeing the code. And if this answer solved your question you might close the question by accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Laravel can't handle your relations automatically because of non-standard relation fields in your DB (`offer_id` in many cases instead of default primary key)

To fix this you must manually provide field names on top of which relations must be built.

**Offer.php**

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    public function offer_countries()
    {
        // Here we provide parent key field name (offer_id) because we don't want to use the primary key for that
        return $this->belongsToMany(OfferCountries::class, null, null, null, 'offer_id');
    }

    public function offer_categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OfferCategory::class, null, null, null, 'offer_id');
    }

    public function offer_tools()
    {
        // Map foreign key to local one 
        return $this->hasMany(OfferTools::class, 'offer_id', 'offer_id');
    }

    public function offer_traffic()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OfferTraffic::class, 'offer_id', 'offer_id');
    }

    //...
}
```

And the last model is `OfferCountries` and `offers` relation. We must provide `relatedKey` argument to tell Eloquent in which field to look for foreign key:

**OfferCountries.php**

```
class OfferCountries extends Model
{
    function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, null, null, null, null, 'offer_id');
    }
}
```

**Related documentation:**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You didn't follow standard naming convention therefore you have to explicitly pass those related keys and table names.

**Offer.php**

```php
use App\OfferCategory;
use App\OfferCountries;
use App\OfferCreative;
use App\OfferTools;
use App\OfferTraffic;

class Offer extends Model {
 public function offer_countries() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(OfferCountries::class, 'offer_offer_countires', 'offer_id', 'offer_countries_id');
 }

 public function offer_categories() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(OfferCategory::class, 'offer_offer_categories', 'offer_id', 'offer_category_id');
 }

 public function offer_creatives() {
     return $this->hasMany(OfferCreative::class, 'offer_id');
 }

 public function offer_tools() {
     return $this->hasMany(OfferTools::class, 'offer_id');
 }

 public function offer_traffic() {
     return $this->hasMany(OfferTraffic::class, 'offer_id');
 }

 public function platforms() {
     return $this->hasMany(Platform::class, 'offer_id');
 }
}
```

**OfferCountries.php**

```php
use App\Offer;

class OfferCountries extends Model {

   function offers() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'offer_offer_countires', 'offer_countries_id', 'offer_id');
    }
}
```